# Django Admin - FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is appended twice to URL when POSTing

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, uwsgi

I have deployed Django to a sub directory (I don't have full control over the server so can't change the way it's deployed).

I added to my settings:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/hub06'
STATIC_URL = FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME + '/static/'
```

Now when I go to `/admin/hub06`, it's working properly, I can login and browse all admin pages. As soon as I do a `POST` request though (adding a new model), the URL gets corrupted.

For example, when editing `/hub06/admin/myapp/car/1`

When I submit the form, it redirects to `/hub06/hub06/admin/myapp/car/`

So it adds script name twice. This is only for `POST` requests in Django admin.

Comment: Why are you on ` /hub06/hub06/admin/myapp/car/1` in the first place?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` needs to end with a slash.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Sorry that was a mistake, when I am editing /hub06/admin/myapp/car/1. I will try adding a slash and let you know if it helps but I think I already tried it last week and it didn't work.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I tried adding the slash. Doesn't help.

Comment: When you look at the URLs that Django generates for regular links (`GET` requests) and those that it generates for `POST` requests, do you see a difference in how the URLs start? (Also, you say "Now when I go to /admin/hub06". This is a typo, right? You mean to say `/hub06/admin/`, right?)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
# NB - this setting is required to make the app work correctly when running
# via ProxyPass from Apache. Otherwise CSRF checks and some redirects will not
# work.
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

Comment: I have the same issue and this doesn't solve the problem unfortunately...

Answer (score 7):

Is this a linux host? is it running apache, nginx? It all depends on how your web server is configured.

If you really must have a url prefix like `/hub06/` then you will need to update any settings in settings.py that return a url such as `LOGIN_URL`, `STATIC_URL`, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` etc to contain the prefix.

I don't think you need to use `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`. Comment that bit out in the `settings.py` and update `urls.py` to add the following for example:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns2 = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'yourapp.views.home', name='Home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hub06/', include(urlpatterns2)),
)
```

Let me know how you go.

Comment: App should not be aware of the prefix of the URL it's running on. Hardcoding paths in whatever `*_URL` variables is not the way you solve the issue.